# What's wrong with this PDF file?

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

I'm trying to read my laptop's manual.

It is published as [a PDF file](http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-14r-5437_reference%20guide_pt-br.pdf), but when I open it either on my Fedora 26 PC using either:

- Evince
- Firefox 54.0
- Chromium 51

all I see is this:

[image]

The file doesn't seem to be empty - it's a 2.6 MB file, and apparently Firefox displays some sort of table of contents. But nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It requires Acrobat, since it is multimedia (which I feel is a bit intrusive and possibly a security risk). Testing with Sumatra and in PDF-XChange exhibits the same issue.

Rather than trying to install Adobe Acrobat Reader, download a manual from Dell such as http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-14r-5437_owner%27s%20manual_en-us.pdf . Search the web on **inspiron 14r-5437 manual** or guide.

Comment: The PDF I'm trying to open was downloaded from Dell's own website - http://www.dell.com/support/home/br/pt/brbsdt1/product-support/product/inspiron-14r-5437/manuals - and when I try to open the page you linked, it redirects me to the one I pasted here.

Comment: Sorry... the English-language file at http://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-14r-5437_owner%27s%20manual_en-us.pdf opens in alternate PDF viewers, as do the others. This is apparently an issue with the Brazilian file. Perhaps there's a European Portuguese version that works?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with the PDF file. It opens as I would expect from any PDF with embedded Multimedia content using Adobe Acrobat Reader.

[image: Screenshot from Acrobat Reader]

It should be noted that using the Up and Down arrows on the keyboard allow you to "change pages", even though this is a single page PDF. Why Dell have decided to distribute this document in this way, we may never know...